# Find the number of employees working under a manager

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery

I have three tables called branch,employee and manager structured like this

```
Table: branch
CREATE TABLE branch (
    id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                          NOT NULL
                          UNIQUE,
    name          FLOAT,
    city          VARCHAR,
    region        VARCHAR,
    postal_code   VARCHAR,
    street        VARCHAR,
    street_number VARCHAR
);

Table: employee
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    surname       VARCHAR,
    name          VARCHAR,
    branch_id     INTEGER REFERENCES BRANCH (ID),
    city          VARCHAR,
    region        VARCHAR,
    street        VARCHAR,
    street_number VARCHAR,
    phone         VARCHAR,
    mobile        VARCHAR,
    vat           VARCHAR,
    amka          VARCHAR,
    at            VARCHAR
);


Table: manager
CREATE TABLE manager (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    employee_id INTEGER REFERENCES employee (id) 
                        UNIQUE
                        NOT NULL
);
```

I want to view the id of each manager and the count of the employees he has under his supervision like this

```
Manager   Number of employees


   1         5
   2        13
```

I have made this so far that shows which branch each manager works on but i don't know how to proceed with the counting.

```
SELECT manager.id AS [Manager id],
       employee.name AS [Manager name],
       branch.name AS [Branch name],
       branch.id AS [Branch id]
  FROM (
           (
               manager
               INNER JOIN
               employee ON manager.employee_id = employee.id
           )
           INNER JOIN
           branch ON employee.branch_id = branch.id
       );
```

The solution i have in mind is first find in which branch each manager is working and then count all the employees of that branch minus one ( the manager). The problem is i don't know how to exactly express it in sql.

Comment: Use COUNT and GROUP BY something like so `select m.id,count(m.employee_id) as ct from manager as m gropu by m.id`

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**. See also: ["Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using and its version.

Comment: Can a branch have more than one manager?

Comment: @stickybit fixed, sorry for that !

Comment: @TimGrewe no each branch can have only one manager

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Do i discard the view i made or do i insert the count somewhere inside it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each branch can only have one manager, you can count the number of employees in a branch and then join the manager to their branch. From there you can count the number of employees in each branch.

```
SELECT manager.id               AS manager_id,
       manager_employee.name    AS manager_name,
       COUNT(employee.id) - 1   AS employee_count
  FROM manager
 INNER JOIN employee AS manager_employee
    ON manager.employee_id = manager_employee.id
 INNER JOIN branch
    ON manager_employee.branch_id = branch.id
 INNER JOIN employee
    ON branch.id = employee.branch_id
 GROUP BY manager.id,
          manager_employee.name
```

Comment: Yea that did the trick . Now what if i want to subtract one from each column ?(The manager shouldn't be counted)

Comment: Nevermind i found it , COUNT(employee.id) -1

Comment: Exactly. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select manager.id as manager, count(employee_id) as 'Number of Empolyee' 
from manager
group by manager.id
```

`COUNT` will result in employee count w.r.t manager `GROUP BY`, as manager_id and employee_id of employee under that manager is saved in the same table.

If the manager table saves data of the manager only , then employee table should also have manager_id just like it has branch_id, so that we know which employee works under which manager. Create employee and manager relation in this case

```
select `manager.id` as manager, count(employee.employee_id) as 'Number of Empolyee' 
from manager join employee on emplyee.manager_id=manager.id
group by `manager.id`
```

Comment: Unfortunately the employee table mustn't have a manager column. A manager is someone from the employee table. The solution i have in mind is first find in which branch each manager is working and then count all the employees of that branch minus one ( the manager). The problem is i don't know how to exactly express it in sql